# OMD : Thruk doesn't detect nagios config

Tags: monitoring, omdistro

I've installed on a CentOS 7 system latest version of OMD (omd-2.90-labs-edition).

It installs ok.
I use the default naemon monitoring engine and Thruk as the web GUI.

I was using before an old version of OMD with Shinken and Thruk.
Naemon seems to work ok, and reuses my host and service definitions.

OMD provides several cores, all of them compatible with Nagios.

But Thruk shows an empty configuration (no hosts, no services)
The log file (`~/var/log/thruk.log`) is empty.

I know the nagios core is working ok by the looking at the logs.

Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to modify the `~/etc/thruk/cgi.cfg` in order to grant permissions to current user to all hosts and services.

Modifying this line and restarting Thruk is enough:

```
authorized_for_admin=myuser
```